# Proving $X= f^{-1}[f[X]]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inverse

If $X \subseteq B$ and $f: A \rightarrow B$ then prove the above. Consider that $X$, $A$ and $B$ are all sets.

If $f$ is injective this would be solved easily but the problem is that $f$ is not necessarily injective.

Comment: That is wrong. Consider $f:\{0,1\} \to \{0\}$ with $X=\{0\}$.

Comment: Do you mean $X\subseteq A$ or $X= f[f^{-1}[X]]$?

Comment: No the problem says X is a subset of B prove that f[X] = f[f^-1[f[X]]] and I wanted to prove what I said to prove this

Comment: and i gave you a counter example. The statement is wrong. Notice that $B$ and $A$ might be disjoint. So $f[X]$ isn't well-defined.

Comment: Thanks for you help